# view object not showing in swift simulator running xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have been working through the Food Tracker app tutorial as a project to learn Swift. I understand that this is full of bugs, but I have been researching ways to correctly format my code. I got to the star rating section, added the red button, separated it into 5 buttons, then added the stars. The stars showed up for a bit, but now do not show up in my simulator at all. I have cleaned my code, disconnected and added images and image code, disconnected and added my IBOutlets, etc. They still are not showing so I am thinking there has to be something I am missing in my code since I am new to this. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import UIKit

class RatingControl: UIView {
    // MARK: Properties

    var rating = 0 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    var ratingButtons = [UIButton]()
    var spacing = 5
    var stars = 5

    // MARK: Initialization

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        let filledStar = UIImage(named: "filledStar")
        let emptyStar = UIImage(named: "emptyStar")

        for _ in 0..<5 {
            let button = UIButton()

            button.setImage(emptyStar, for: UIControlState())
            button.setImage(filledStar, for: .selected)
            button.setImage(filledStar, for: [.highlighted, .selected])

            button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false

            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RatingControl.ratingButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchDown);            ratingButtons += [button]
            addSubview(button)
        }
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        // Set the button's width and height to a square the size of the frame's height.
        let buttonSize = Int(frame.size.height)
        var buttonFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: buttonSize, height: buttonSize)

        // Offset each button's origin by the length of the button plus spacing.
        for (index, button) in ratingButtons.enumerated() {
            buttonFrame.origin.x = CGFloat(index * (buttonSize + spacing))
            button.frame = buttonFrame
        }
        updateButtonSelectionStates()
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize : CGSize {
        let buttonSize = Int(frame.size.height)
        let width = (buttonSize + spacing) * stars

        return CGSize(width: width, height: buttonSize)
    }

    // MARK: Button Action

    func ratingButtonTapped(_ button: UIButton) {
        rating = ratingButtons.index(of: button)! + 1

        updateButtonSelectionStates()
    }

    func updateButtonSelectionStates() {
        for (index, button) in ratingButtons.enumerated() {
            // If the index of a button is less than the rating, that button should be selected.
            button.isSelected = index < rating
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your init?() method, you've missed adding button to ratingButtons array as a result nothing is turned up when the array is enumerated and accessed, and it is empty

Please add the following

```
self.ratingsButton.append(button)
```

right after

```
addSubview(button)
```

Hopefully the buttons will start showing up.